# free and easy caching maven repository

Tags: maven, repository

I want easy control of artifacts in our corporate repository. I want search artifact in GUI and add it to corporate repository. Users of repository can access only artifacts, which added in such way. Which repositories support it? Preferable for free?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Security? Or What?

Comment: BTW: You are talking about promotion of artifacts which is available  in Artifactory or Nexus (but in the commerical versions).

Comment: My boss want to control which libraries and frameworks we using.

Comment: Commercial version starts from 1200$/year. Maybe there is cheaper way to control artifact list?

Comment: Based on the requirements you have written there isn't. You can do it manually ([may be with the help of a plugin](https://github.com/ffray/maven-dependencytransfer-plugin)) but i think that's not really option. Why does your boss need to control which libraries you are using? License issues? Security? Or just not trusting people?

Comment: I see in nexus routing and repository targets. I'll try to use it. There is different reasons to control artefacts. I think the biggest achievment is : We have uncommon situation - not one project per many developers, but many projects per each developer. So we all use some libraries and frameworks and no one knows what is in others's projects. If developer is ill, it takes time to learn frameworks. We want to make some convention about what we use. If we control repository content, convention will be automatically - without adding artifacts to repository, project will not build on teamcity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question is "any free repository". I choose nexus for example. My requirements is achived on maven level with any repository. Artifact control in repository is bad idea because you can easy break build of old versions. AFAIK there is no so smart repository artifact management system, which deals with branches in svn. I use maven-enforcer plugin now. I found the solution in another question : [user friendly artifact procurement in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011656/user-friendly-artifact-procurement-in-maven).