# user friendly artifact procurement in maven

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, artifactory, archiva

We need convention about libraries and frameworks we use in our team. It will be best if we just type somewhere something like "allowed to use org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3" and then this dependency and all transitive dependencies is allowed automatically. Which repository and which capability supports it? I try procurement capability of nexus, but it works with already loaded artifacts and not allows/disallows transitive dependencies(IMHO nexus procurement implementation is just not user-friendly point of view). I also try routing capability of nexus - i make "block all but ..."( ((?!plugins).)* ) rule, but seems that only one such rule allowed.

Comment: wow! Seems like it's better than i want.

Comment: Mark, you can write it as answer, i'll add coment then with my realisation and accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest using the [Maven Enforcer Rules plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/).